# Определенное кол-во переборов

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, перебор

Для начала пользователь вводит цифру(любую). После этого программа должна сделать циклов для переборов столько, сколько ввел пользователь. Например, пользователь ввел `5`, тогда программа должна создать массив с 5 элементами и все заполнить нулями. `[0,0,0,0,0]`. Вопрос как перебрать все цифры от 0 до 100 и вывести массив в консоль(Просто при каждой итерации `print(array)`), при условии что мы не знаем сколько нужно циклов чтобы перебрать каждый элемент массива?

Если как указанно выше пользователь ввел 5 то программа должна сначала перебрать последний элемент от `[0,0,0,0,0]` до `[0,0,0,0,100]`. После идет перебор последнего и предпоследнего элемента от `[0,0,0,0,0]` до `[0,0,0,100,100]` И так до первого элемента.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, что вы хотите, то вам нужен `itertools.product`

```
from itertools import product

number = int(input('Введите цифру:'))
variants = range(0, 100+1)

for item in product(variants, repeat=number):
    print(list(item))
    # Если нужно перебирать с первого элемента, а не с последнего
    # то можно просто разворачивать список перед его выводом
    # вот так:
    # print(list(reversed(item)))
```

Comment: Спасибо все работает, а можно сделать тоже самое, только в обратном порядка с 1 элемента до последнего?

Comment: @Log1c0, я добавил в мой ответ комментарий о том, как сделать в обратном порядке

Comment: `itertools.combinations` как тоже рабочий вариант можно сделать

Comment: @Twiss, combinations здесь не подходит. Для него (100, 0) и (0, 100) - это один и тот же вариант. Если перебор с combinations выдал один из них, то второго уже не выдаст никогда.